# Server Functions cannot be called during initial render. This would create a fetch waterfall

Tags: next.js

Route API:

[image: route APi]

Handle Submit:

[image: handleSubmit]

I have a problem when using fetch. In fact I want to create a record in my table. using zod when I click on the button to create the record calls the handle submit function which fetches to ../pages/api/boards but I receive an error message in my console "Server Functions cannot be called during initial render. This would create a fetch waterfall. Try to use a Server Component to pass data to Client Components instead"....